# Closure Guidance : Why was my question closed

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

I recently asked the [question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/66647/create-a-matrix-effect-in-programming) in code golf, I have followed the standard template :

I have provided :

- Sample input
- Sample output
- Sample code & rules

what else this community need in order to make the question clear,i cant get the point of closure behind it,myself from non-english country & if my question lacks proper english you could edit & reframe the question

kindly clarify what made it close it as unclear

thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I can't speak to why the other users voted to close your question, but I would have closed it myself and here's why:

First of all, it's more of an art contest than a programming contest. Challenges like that aren't on topic here since the site is about programming.

Popularity contests, i.e. challenges which are scored by the number of votes, are difficult to do well. In particular, they need very specific guidelines on what is expected for the task and what makes an entry deserving of votes. In this case, the only rule is "output random characters and say 'matrix effect'."

Even if this were well specified, it would be hard to make it sufficiently distinct from [Make the Matrix Digital Rain using the shortest amount of code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/17285/make-the-matrix-digital-rain-using-the-shortest-amount-of-code).

I encourage you to post your challenge to the [Sandbox for Proposed Challenges](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges) where you can get meaningful feedback from the community before the challenge is posted to the main site.